# Select2 поиск по скрытым атрибутам

Tags: javascript, select2

Плагин Select2 (http://select2.github.io/) позволяет фильтровать < option > по его тексту.

Как отфильтровать данные по data-атрибутам? Некоторую информацию нужно скрыть от пользователя, но позволить ему искать по ней, например штрих-код товара.

Comment: видимо править ядро плагина, не?

Comment: @Jean-Claude хотелось бы что-нибудь проще

Answer (score 1):

Я бы попробовал сделать например как то так:

1. В методе на сервере который будет отдавать *фильтрованный список*, осуществляем фильтрацию на основании пользовательского ввода;
2. Получившийся массив данных в предыдущем пункте формируем соответствующим образом: форматируем строку которая будет отображаться пользователю(в нее включаем только ту информацию которую хотим показать пользователю), если надо *склеиваем* ее.
3. Данные из пункта преобразовываем/конвертируем в `json` и отдаем клиенту;